# Router not working for identical modules. No error

Tags: node.js, express, router

I am trying to use the express router for a simple project here is my main app.js file:

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const path = require("path");
const index = require("./routes/index");
const error = require(__dirname + "/routes/error");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use("/",index);
app.use("/new",error);


app.listen(4000);
```

This is my index file which is exporting and rendering with no problem.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is my error file which is following the exact same logic when you send a get request to "/new" but it says "Cannot GET /new" and no other errors. Please tell me what is going on here.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/new",function(req,res){
    res.render("error");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Note:** I have an index.ejs and error.ejs file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a '/new' in your route URL.

You're going

```
app.use("/new",error);
```

Which means all routes to this router will start with a '/new'.

Then in your router you're defining a route as '/new'

```
router.get("/new",function(req,res){
    res.render("error");
});
```

To access this route you would therefor need to navigate to "/new/new"

Have you tried the GET route with the following URL?

```
http://localhost:4000/new/new
```

I have of course assumed that you have saved your project and restarted app.js, either manually or automatically (nodemon, etc).

Comment: Thank you. It works on new/new, So how can I get it to route to /new ? Can you please explain the logic so I understand

Comment: In your error.js replace app.get("/new",...) with app.get("/",...)

Comment: So then the actual route is always defined in the app.use portion ?

Comment: By passing app.use a string as the first parameter, what you're saying in lamens terms is "every route inside this file will start with this string", so if you go 'app.use("/foo", foo.js), all routes declared inside foo.js will start with '/foo'.Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does. Thank you.